# Paginação de um SelectBox Dinamico em arquivos php diferentes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-datatables

Boa tarde, eu estou enfrentando um problema na criação de uma paginação.

**Javascript**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#estados').on('change', function(e){
                var estado = document.getElementById('estados')
                var estadovl = document.getElementById('estadovl')
                estadovl.value = estado.options[estado.selectedIndex].value
            });
        });
</script>
```

**HTML - Página 1**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4"> 
            <h1>Cidade Escolha</h1>
            <form class="text-center" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="form1" action='cidades.php'>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <select class="form-control" id="estados" name="estados">
                        <option>Escolha seu Estado</option>
                        <?php 
                            $query = "select * from estados;";
                            $dt = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dt)){
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['estado_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['nome'];?></option>
                            <?php }; ?>

                   <input type="text" id="estadovl" name="estadovl" hidden="hidden">
                 </select>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" placeholder="enviar">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>






    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Já conectado com o banco de dados, na primeira página o cliente irá escolher um estado brasileiro (estados estão armazenados no mysql), o valor da opção será jogada para o `<input type="text" id="estadovl" name="estadovl" hidden="hidden">` como mencionado no código em javascript e irá ser redirecionado para a página 2.

**PHP - Página 2**

```
include ('conection.php'); 

/*if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}else{
    $page = 1;
}*/

$numpag = 10;
$pagina = (isset( $_GET['pagina'])) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$inicio = $pagina * $numpag;




$query = "SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE estado_id = ".$_GET['estadovl']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT $inicio,$numpag";
$dt = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($dt);
```

Nessa página, ele encontrará todas as cidades pertencentes ao estado escolhido. As cidades (que também estão armazenadas no banco de dados) são mostradas atavés do código acima. Acontece que tenho que fazer uma paginação limitando 10 cidades por página, porém esse "cidades.php" não abre como "cidades.php?page=1" como foi mudado na variável `$pagina = (isset( $_GET['pagina'])) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;`, além disso, os "link do span" constam que o estado não foi escolhido.

```
<h1>Cidade Escolha</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dt)){?>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>
        <div class='panel panel-default'>
          <div class='panel-title'>
            <h2 style='text-align:center;'><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></h2>
          </div>
          <div class='panel-body'>
            <p><h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3></p>
            <p>Endereço: <?php echo $row['cep'] ?></p>
            <p>Telefone:</p>      
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <div class="pull-left">
    <span>
      <?php
        $pgquery = "SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE estado_id = ".$_GET['estadovl']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY nome ASC;";
        $pgdt = mysqli_query($conn, $pgquery);
        $pgrowcount = mysqli_num_rows($pgdt); 
        $totalpag = ceil($pgrowcount/$numpag);
        for($i = 1; $i<= $totalpag; $i++){
          echo "<a href='cidades.php?page=".$i."'>$i</a>";
        }
      ?>
    </span>
  </div>
```

[image: Página 1]

[image: Página 2]

[image: Página Erro - paginações]

Comment: Possui a aplicação hospedada  pra ver isso rodando? Li o código e não ta fazendo sentido, sua parte de javascript voce pega o valor escolhido e não faz nada com ele. Não consigo ver o parametro pagina em lugar nenhum do HTML sendo enviado. Você pode estar se perdendo nas definições de chamadas Ajax e Interpretação código PHP.

Comment: Eu adicionei imagens para melhorar a pergunta, com o parametro página corrigido, o GET página é referente ao "pagina=" na paginação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom antes de mais nada eu te recomendo dar uma pesquisada sobre [sql injection](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Eu dei uma olhada no seu código e acho que isso pode ajudar:

- *Levando em consideração que quando você navega pra página `cidades.php`, você já tem o valor `estado` pela variável `$_GET['estadovl']`*

Na observação você diz que os resultado está pulando os 10 primeiros registros, isso porque sua variável `$inicio` começa do `10` e não do `0`, alterar esse código na página 2 já deve resolver essa questão:

```
// De 
$inicio = $pagina * $numpag;

// Para
$inicio = ( $pagina - 1 ) * $numpag;
```

Já sobre a paginação eu te aconselho adicionar o estado junto com o link a página

```
// De
echo "<a href='cidades.php?page=".$i."'>$i</a>"; 

// Para
echo "<a href='cidades.php?page=".$i."&estadovl=".$_GET['estadovl']."'>$i</a>";
```

Comment: eu consertei a variável `$inicio`  e o echo que você mencionou, Arrumou a questão dos erros. Porém todos os links das paginações só seguem as mesmas informações da pagina 1, ou seja, altera a URL mas não as informações. Só mexi nesses códigos que você mandou arrumar.

Comment: Arrumei!! o nome do GET e do URL estavam diferentes

Answer (score 0):

Bom, pelo que to vendo nos prints o problema está nos estados. Você tem que passar os parametro estadovl via pra pegar no $_GET['estadovl'].
Sua URL tem que ficar http://.../cidades.php?pagina=1&estadovl=MG 
Ta faltando mudar nesse lugar aqui também:

```
  for($i = 1; $i<= $totalpag; $i++){
          echo "<a href='cidades.php?page=".$i."'>$i</a>";
        }
```

Deve ficar algo do tipo:

```
 for($i = 1; $i<= $totalpag; $i++){
              echo "<a href='cidades.php?page=".$i."'&estadovl=".$_GET['estadovl'].">$i</a>";
            }
```